# Is there a way to programmatically control Alexa?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I want to programmatically ask my Echo Dot to do something.

I'd like to make a program that does something like this:

`alexa_api.ask('play music')`

And after that, my Echo Dot starts playing music...

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please descibe your use case what you really want to achieve here ?

Comment: What I'd like to do is a web page that displays the plans of my house, and I can click on the rooms to turn the lights on/off, play music, etc.

Comment: you can use google assistance and if you have echo dot you can control echo dot in speaker mode using google assistant if that suits you, alexa as of now does'nt allow your use case as of now, if you want more discussion let me know

Answer (score 0):

No. Interactions are triggered by the user of the Alexa device.

It is not possible to trigger an Alexa device to perform a function unless it was first requested by the user.